# Genesis 1:5 How can God call the light "Day" when light and day are two different concepts?

Tags: hebrew, genesis, contradiction, grammar, creation

> (Genesis 1:5) **ויקרא אלהים ׀ לאור יום** ולחשך קרא לילה ויהי־ערב ויהי־בקר יום אחד׃ פ
>
> (My translation of the bold part) **And God called to the light, "Day"**

Just to make it clear, I understand that when something is being named with the verb קרא, the thing being named is often treated like an indirect object. Since we don't really do this in English, my translation might not be the best, but bear with me for now.

My question is this. **How can God call/name the light "Day" when light and day are two distinct, albeit  related, concepts?**

Here are a couple of thoughts.

1. The lamed prefix can also mean "for." What if we translate as follows

   > And God named 'Day' for the light

   I like this translation, because instead of assigning the name yom to the light as if yom and light were the exact same thing, he instead assigns the name yom **for** the light. That is, God assigns the name yom **for the sake of the light** or **to accommodate the light** or **to accompany the light**. I think this translation, while it might not be as pretty as the traditional rendering, more accurately reflects reality.
2. What if God doesn't actually call the light 'Day,' but instead calls **to** the light 'Day?' The word "to" seems to suggest the possibility that this calling isn't exact, but rather approximate. I mean, if I run **to** or **towards** the East, that might mean that I am running in the general direction of East but perhaps a few degrees off. Could it be that the verb קרא assigns a name approximately to the indirect object but not exactly? Perhaps an examination of uses of the word קרא would help answer this question.
3. Notice the traditional rendering is, God called **the** light day. That is, some light is day but some might not be. I might concede to naming the photons from the sun, "day," but I wouldn't call the photons from my electrical lamp "day."

Comment: I think you have missed the point of the exercise. Two items were separated (first) and then, as separate distinct items they were identified by names (second). Doesn't matter what the names were. It was important to untangle them and to identify them as separate items. So we know that they are two different things, with different names. Otherwise we will confuse them . . .  which Eve, then Adam, immediately did, assisted by an helpful Serpent. _If the light that is in thee be darkness ... how great is that darkness !_

Comment: I see, so you mean the point of the naming is to show that they are distinct. I guess the part that troubles me a little is that God calls the light "yom" and the darkness "laylah," even though owr ≠ yom and choshek ≠ laylah.

Comment: There is a period of time during which one state prevails. And there is another period of time in which another state prevails. It is time that separates light and dark. And one luminary rules the Day. And another luminary rules the Night. Eventually, they will be separated even further - by a great gulf - forever. Now, do you see it ? _Day unto day uttereth speech, and night unto night sheweth knowledge_ Psalm 19:2.

Comment: There are two _forms of light_. One is a pale reflection of what Light really is. It rules the Night. The other is a blazing source of fiery light. It rules the Day. Beware that the "light" which is in ye, be not Darkness. How great is _that_ darkness.

Comment: It's all about the Law and the Gospel @Pascal's Wager. It's nothing to do with photons.

Comment: The previous question about this subject focused on 'separation'. This question is different - it focuses on 'naming'. I do not think they are duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepositions do not have concrete meanings of their own. They have abstract meanings and receive concrete meanings in combination with verbs and/or nouns.<sup>1</sup>

In the case of קרא, we have an overwhelming amount of occurrences where קרא+ל means "call", i.e. "name". The first suggestion in your answer, that God called out or named something for the sake of the light (whatever that may mean!), is very different from this. One may wonder how a native would have understood that in this particular case קרא+ל does not mean what it usually means. It would have been very confusing.

I am not entirely sure what is meant with the second suggestion. That God called out to the light, i.e. addressed the light, saying "day"? But why would he do that? Unless I'm missing something, this does not resolve any awkwardness in the traditional reading.

To sum up, I think the traditional reading should be maintained. Note that "day" and "night" are not just names for time frames. For instance, when we say "it is day", do we really mean that the current falls within a certain time frame? It seems more straightforward to understand it as "it is light", and conversely "it is night" as "it is dark (outside)". It seems to me that the concept of day as a specific time frame is secondary: it is the time during which it is light. Thus you can understand this verse as defining what daytime is. Does that resolve the awkwardness you are experiencing? There are parallels for this: to mind come Ps. 139:12, "darkness does not hide for you: night is as light as the day, darkness is like light" and Gen. 29:7, "it is still day".

As for the third point: you have to imagine primordial times. There is no light other than that just created.

<sup>1: For a good introduction to the study of prepositions, see the introduction in [Jenni, E., *Die hebräischen Präpositionen*, Vol. 1: *Die Präposition Beth* (1992)](https://www.kohlhammer.de/wms/instances/KOB/appDE/Theologie/Altes-Testament/Die-Praeposition-Beth/).</sup>

Comment: The problem is, what if I have my lamp on but its nighttime? The light from the lamp isn't "day." How can God call/name the light "Day" when light and day are two distinct, albeit related, concepts?

Comment: @Pascal'sWager these are primordial times, there are no lamps...

Comment: That's actually a really good point. :)  I guess all the light which existed was natural light. So maybe God labelled this natural light, "yom." So any photon in existence, at least during this primordial time, could truly be called "yom." It seems like a plausible explanation to me, at least so far. Am I understanding you accurately?

Comment: @Pascal'sWager yes, that's my line of thought.

Comment: I like this answer, but perhaps it could be strengthened with some examples of the word יום being used in the sense of natural light elsewhere in scripture. I mean, it seems yom is mostly used to refer to either the time of day or the duration of 24 hours. I'm having trouble finding verses where it actually refers to the light itself.

Comment: @Pascal'sWager I've added two references. But there may be some misunderstanding. I'm not suggesting that in Genesis, God defines the word יום as "light", or that you may use it in sentences where you would use "light" (e.g., "the stars of the day" instead of "of the light" in Ps. 148:3). I'm suggesting that he defines the *concept* "day" (יום) *by* it-being-light. Without clocks, you cannot define a day as 24 hours.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand you a little better. My original problem still remains, however. In Genesis 1:5, it seems as if God is naming the light, "yom." But if yom and light are not interchangeable, then this seems like a contradiction. I mean, when the name "Israel" is given to Jacob, Jacob and Israel become almost interchangeable words. You can substitute Israel for Jacob, and the meaning isn't changed. But you can't substitute Yom for Owr.

Comment: @Pascal'sWager perhaps Isa. 47:1 or Jer. 6:30 are helpful if you are looking for cases where קרא does not indicate a simple equivalence? But I would maintain that for this particular case it does indicate that. The meaning of יום as a time-frame is secondary, it is the time *that it is light*. God calls Israel him-who-is-Jacob, he calls day that-which-is-light. The only difference: there is only one Jacob, so the two become identical, but there are multiple forms of light, so these two do not become interchangeable. Again, during creation they *were* interchangeable, so קרא is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There are two very different concepts, as you point out.

One is the concept of time. Daytime and Nighttime. 
The other is the concept of light. But 'darkness' is not total because there is a luminary created to rule the night. Thus the nighttime is not pitch black. It is ruled over by moon and stars. Thus there is a kind of light at nighttime.

But the nighttime light is either sparse and extremely sparing, in the very nature of the stars themselves, or it is a dim, reflected light which is not reliable (waxing and waning and sometimes not there at all).

> Day unto day uttereth speech and night unto night teacheth knowledge. Psalm 19:2 [KJV].

The psalmist says not 'day unto night' ... but 'day unto day' and 'night unto night'. They are two different environments - two different time zones - ruled by different bodies.

*They are two different realms.*

The 'light' at nighttime is a pale reflection of what 'Light' really is. The sun is fiery light, of itself. It is a *source* of light. It is, as it were, a living thing, pouring out energy - heat and light. Under its influence vegetation grows and creatures are warmed and live.

Nothing grows under the cold, pale, sparse, intermittent 'light' of the moon with its mere reflection of the (temporarily) hidden sun.

These things are an allegory. They were created to teach us. Made to instruct us. And scripture is full of the allusions of night and dark, of daytime and nighttime, of cold and heat.

Two different concepts, as you point out, are linked together. Two realms appear, which, in their very nature, cannot co-exist together. They must be separate.

And there will come an age in which they will be separated forever.

> Ye are all the children of light, and the children of the day: we are not of the night, nor of darkness.Therefore let us not sleep, as do others; but let us watch and be sober. I Thessalonians 5:5.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Keelan We have approached the question from different aspects, I would say.

Comment: That's clear, but every approach should still answer the question. Can you clarify which sentence(s) do that here? I cannot find them.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to see deeper studies of historical understanding but the cultural significance is not addressed in that the earth was formed in darkness and then light source(s) created. From the very beginning we discover the physics of creation in that earth was already spinning by the time light burst upon the scene. The length of a day begins in darkness and ends with darkness. We have 24 hours in a day and the first 12 hours are in darkness according to Judaism and the light follows darkness to end it. This is biblical prophecy in the creation sequence that not only foretells the final outcome of God's will for mankind but also how every event is in his control.

Where the telcos recognition of a day exists, it was Constantine whom changed time keeping initiation and conclusion to the midnight- midnight model of today.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It is not true that the 'first twelve hours' of the Jewish day are 'in darkness'. The day covers the waning of one period of light and the waxing of the next period of light.

Comment: The measure of a day began with the first day of creation which began in darkness and then light was created afterwards. When that light faded, it was the end of the first day. Earth was in darkness before the end of the first day and before light was created.

Comment: Since on the first day, there was no sun, therefore 'evening' and 'morning' do not relate to the apparent motion of the sun. Thus they convey intrinsic concepts. 'Evening' conveys the end of one phase of state and 'morning' conveys the beginning of another phase of state. But when there _is_ a sun, then the day begins with waning light and the day ends with new, full light. Conceptually.

Comment: That may be for modern conception of time for the midnight- midnight model instituted by Constantine but this is about 6000 years ago when the ancients historically looked up into the sky and the day was ended as the first 2nd magnitude start appeared in the sky. In idiomatic Aramaic they would say the day began "in a twinkling of an eye." To them, historically, after daylight ended, the new 24 hour day began.